# Embedding css in angular 2 project with jspm

Tags: angular, systemjs, jspm

I am trying to embed now my CSS in my angular 2 project, so I installed the css plugin and configured

```
  "src": {
            "main": "App",
            "defaultExtension": "ts",
            "meta": {
                "*.js": {
                    "loader": false
                },
                "*.ts": {
                    "loader": "ts"
                },
                "*.css": {
                    "loader": "css",
                    'typings': true
                }
            }
        },
```

as well as my component

`import RatesTableStyle from './RatesTable.css!';`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'RatesTable',
    moduleId: __moduleName,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    styles: [RatesTableStyle],
    template: RatesTableTemplate
})
```

but I am getting an error of
 Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings.
any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Angular is expecting that each item in this array to be a string of styles:

```
styles:[ `h1{
           ...
          }
         h2{
           ...
           }`
];
```

You are proving a whole class instead. If this class is supposed to return an array, you just need to call a new instance of it.

Comment: but its not something I control as I am using jspm css plugin

Comment: Try this: clear your styles array, place the RatesTableStyle in the constructor of your component class and console.log it. Check its methods and properties and verify if any of then can return a string.

Comment: good idea, so I put a breakpoint and I get back a custom objects with getters and setters but ya, not a simple array, I wonder why the jspm is not doing what it is supposed to :/

Comment: basically I get 'invoke property getter' with the text plugin

Answer (score 0):

ok found the solution, make sue NO css plugin is installed (remove from jspm config entirely) and set:

```
import RatesTableTemplate from './RatesTable.html!text';
import RatesTableStyle from './RatesTable.css!text';

@Component({
    selector: 'RatesTable',
    moduleId: __moduleName,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    styles: [RatesTableStyle],
    template: RatesTableTemplate
})
...
```

Hope it helps someone

Sean